# hyperlink word table of figures in pdf

Tags: microsoft-word, adobe-acrobat

I save a word document with both Table of Contents and Table of Figures. I create a PDF using Adobe Acrobat.
The table of contents in the PDF document are hyperlinked. The table of figures is not.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I researched this issue while helping students at my university format their theses and dissertations.  It appears that Adobe Acrobat (or at least the extension for Microsoft Word) has issues that prevent hyperlinks in the table of figures from appearing.  The problem is with the software, not the users.

Comment: thanks for your response. I did as many searches as I could and came to the conclusion that it wasn't possible. I appreciate your response.

Comment: There's an accept button for that XD